Return type of a method in java and why use it?
interface Copyable{
    Object copy();
}

class Book implements Copyable{
    String bookName;
    String bookID;
    public Book(String bookName,String bookID){
        this.bookID = bookID ;
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
    public Object copy(){
        return new Book(bookName,bookID);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book1 =  new Book("demo","1");
        System.out.println(book1);
        Book book2 = book1.copy(); // error
        Book book2 = (Book)book1.copy(); // right
    }
}



in this java code , why it get fault when I don't use the cast ? it must match the return's type(in this case , the type is Object) in java ? but in the heap , I get the Book instance. the purpose of this case is ensure the type safety ?


the compiler does not execute the code, it does not check what runtime type a method will return; 2) copy() could return any type, a String for example, which cannot be assigned to a Book; 3) given in the Java Language Specification 15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =: "If the type of the right-hand operand is not assignment compatible with the type of the variable (§5.2), then a compile-time error occurs." (original emphasis)


Because you defined the method to return java.lang.Object; which is the root of the Java type hierarchy. Normally, I'd suggest making Copyable generic but there is already a Cloneable interface that you should be using instead. Like,
class Book implements Cloneable {
    String bookName;
    String bookID;

    public Book(String bookName, String bookID) {
        this.bookID = bookID;
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    @Override
    public Book clone() {
        return new Book(bookName, bookID);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book book1 = new Book("demo", "1");
        System.out.println(book1);
        Book book2 = book1.clone();
        System.out.println(book2);
    }
}

Also, a more traditional implementation would be something like
@Override
public Book clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return (Book) super.clone();
}


so why I can use a Book instance to return a Object type? because Book extends Object?

@user22873067 Yes: a Book is an Object

@user22873067 because every Book is an Object, but not every Object is a Book.

The first code example is not how clone() should be implemented.

@MarkRotteveel there is no requirement to implement Cloneable by utilizing the clone() method inherited from Object. The actual problem is suggesting Cloneable in the first place. The OP’s interface declared a common public method for all of its implementations whereas the Cloneable interface is empty. In other words, it’s not a replacement for the OP’s interface at all. Not to speak of all the subtle problems above a beginner’s head.

Not a strict requirement, but the API for Object.clone() says: "By convention, the returned object should be obtained by calling super.clone."
